# Most Secure Exchange of Keys

Tags: encryption, public-key, key-exchange

Given both Alice and Bob must exchange IP addresses to perform such an operation, what is the most secure way Alice and Bob can exchange public keys between two mobile devices without having to rely on a third-party server or hosted database of a website?

And yes, while i understand the key is PUBLIC, my goal is to exchange keys WITHOUT the key being stored on a third-party server or hosted database, accessible to the site administrator.